# Converting fetch PUT request into axios request

Tags: javascript, axios, fetch-api

I have been using `fetch` on the frontend to make a `PUT` request. My code looked like the following:

```
fetch(url, {
  headers: {
    'content-type': 'png',
  },
  method: 'PUT',
  body: file,
})
```

I am trying to write the same using `axios` but doesn't seem to be working

```
await axios.put(url, { 
     data: { 
        body: file 
    },
    headers: {
       'content-type': 'png',
    },
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [`axios.put`](https://github.com/axios/axios#axiosputurl-data-config) signature:

`axios.put(url[, data[, config]])`

The second argument is treated as `data`, so your `headers` end up as part of the request body.

Further, `data: { body: file },` is redundant. `axios.put()`'s `data` argument is *already* treated as body.

So you can either do:

```
await axios.put(url, file,
  {
    headers: {
      'content-type': 'png'
    }
  }
)
```

or:

```
await axios.put(url, {},
  {
    data: file,
    headers: {
      'content-type': 'png'
    }
  }
)
```

Or, for even more resemblance with `fetch` API,

```
await axios(url,
  {
    method: 'PUT',
    data: file,
    headers: {
      'content-type': 'png'
    }
  }
)
```